# How can I connect to my linux server with Mac using the credentials of one of the users on the linux box?

Tags: linux, mac, finder, smb, pathfinder

How can I connect to my linux server with Mac (Finder and/or Pathfinder apps) using the credentials of one of the users on the linux box?? I am using SMB.

The linux box is running Centos 6, Mac is Mountain Lion.

Right now it only connects as root, which means I constantly have to reset the user/permissions on the files/folders via SSH.

Comment: This is most likely an issue with your Samba configuration on the Centos box, rather than with the Mac. What are you using to create the file share on the Linux box?

Comment: Remember that you probably need to add Samba users in addition to the users on the system.

Comment: Squeezy - right on. Added the proper user as samba user, edited smb.conf for that user to be the default guest. Done.